# Multiple Async calls, how to deal with responses in a way that make sense

Tags: c#, .net, api, async-await, response

I am making multiple async calls to a couple of different URLS, both urls should return the same result but i would like to compare the results from both or check for certain values in the responses. i am not sure how to compare or look for specific values in the responses outside of status codes, is there an easy way to do this? also would like to take note of the response and if it was a failure i want to be able to keep track of that later in my code to not use that url again and im not sure how i would go about this

Code:

```
private async Task<ClientModel> getClientInfoAsync(string clientID)
    {
        
        ClientModel c = null;
       
        try
        {
            
            var client = new HttpClient();
            //Start requests for all of them
            var requests = urls.Select
                (
                url => client.GetAsync(getURL(url, "Client", clientID))
                ).ToList();
            //Wait for all the requests to finish
            await Task.WhenAll(requests);

            //Get the responses
            var responses = requests.Select
                (
                    task => task.Result
                );
           
            foreach (var r in responses)
            {
                
                // Extract the message body
                var s = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                    
                          
                if (r.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    c = r.Content.ReadAsAsync<ClientModel>().Result;                        
                    SetLastSuccessfulCommunicationDetails();  //after this call HERE I THINK IS WHERE I WOULD COMPARE RESPONSES AND GO FROM THERE                     

                }
                
            }
           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errMsg = "Error getting the client info";
            //...catch error code here...
        }
        
        return c;
    }
```

Basically im unsure of how to deal with the responses and only return one client model (c) based on my comparison and status of the response.  let me know if i need to include any further information

Comment: "a couple of different URLS": does this literally mean you know you're dealing with two URLs, or will there be multiple URLs to compare with one another? What kind of comparison are you looking to perform?

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can answer this for you. How similar or different are the responses? Does the order of the response matter? If all the responses "agree" then what does it matter which individual response you will use as a basis for your result.

Comment: for now it is just two urls, but it can be more later as far as similar or different the responses, they should return the same responses outside of failure because a url is down returning a failure. i guess i just want to verify they return the same result in the off chance that they do not and at very least log differences, hope that clarifies a bit

Comment: to clarify a bit more as well, if the responses agree you are right i do not care which response i use, i am wanting to use it more as if URL #2 responds with a failure for one reason or another but #1 is a success i want to keep #1 results and later not use URL #2 because it failed this task and any further calls to that URL will not return successes because this initial one failed. I guess i am unsure if i even need to worry about if one fails in the async calls and always just call both URLs because the time to do so is irrelevant

Comment: @Enigmativity yes i think that would be fine for the most part

Comment: @Ledz3p - I've updated my answer with a "first successful" solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can assume that you have a method that looks like this:

```
private Task<ClientModel> DetermineClientModelFromResponses(IEnumerable<string> responses)
```

...then you can use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;`.

It let's you do this:

```
private async Task<ClientModel> GetClientInfoAsync(string clientID) =>
    await DetermineClientModelFromResponses(
        await Observable.Using(
            () => new HttpClient(),
            client =>
                urls
                    .ToObservable()
                    .SelectMany(url => Observable.FromAsync(() => client.GetAsync(getURL(url, "Client", clientID))))
                    .Where(response => response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    .SelectMany(response => Observable.FromAsync(() => response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()))
                    .ToArray()));
```

...or, alternatively, this:

```
private async Task<ClientModel> GetClientInfoAsync(string clientID) =>
    await DetermineClientModelFromResponses(
        await Observable.Using(
            () => new HttpClient(),
            client =>
            (
                from url in urls.ToObservable()
                from response in Observable.FromAsync(() => client.GetAsync(getURL(url, "Client", clientID)))
                where response.IsSuccessStatusCode
                from text in Observable.FromAsync(() => response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
                select text
            ).ToArray()));
```

---

If you're OK with first successful response wins, then this should work for you, but you need to ensure you have at least one succeed:

```
private async Task<ClientModel> GetClientInfoAsync(string clientID) =>
    await Observable.Using(
        () => new HttpClient(),
        client =>
        (
            from url in urls.ToObservable()
            from response in Observable.FromAsync(() => client.GetAsync(getURL(url, "Client", clientID)))
            where response.IsSuccessStatusCode
            from text in Observable.FromAsync(() => response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ClientModel>())
            select text
        ).Take(1));
```

---

To make this more robust to errors you have a few strategies.

I remodelled you code to make a simple example:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var result = (string)"no result";
    try
    {
        result = await GetClientInfoAsync("123");
    }
    catch (NotImplementedException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

private List<string> urls = new List<string>() { "Hello" };

private async Task<string> GetClientInfoAsync(string clientID) =>
    await Observable.Using(
        () => new HttpClient(),
        client =>
        (
            from url in urls.ToObservable()
            from response in Observable.FromAsync(() => Test1(url))
            from text in Observable.FromAsync(() => Test2(response))
            select $"{clientID}:{text}"
        )
            .Concat(Observable.Return<string>(null))
            .Take(1));

private Random _random = new Random();

Task<string> Test1(string url)
{
    if (_random.NextDouble() > 0.3)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Test1!");
    }
    return Task.Run(() => $"{url}!");
}

Task<string> Test2(string response)
{
    if (_random.NextDouble() > 0.3)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Test2!");
    }
    return Task.Run(() => $"{response}#");
}
```

This code will end `GetClientInfoAsync` as soon as there's an exception and it lets it bubble up to the `Main` method. That might not be sufficient for you.

One alternative is to add normal `try`/`catch` code to each of `Test1` and `Test2` to ensure they never fail.

Alternatively, you can add "try again" functionality quite easily.

```
private async Task<string> GetClientInfoAsync(string clientID) =>
    await Observable.Using(
        () => new HttpClient(),
        client =>
        (
            from url in urls.ToObservable()
            from response in Observable.Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => Test1(url))).Retry(5)
            from text in Observable.Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => Test2(response))).Retry(5)
            select $"{clientID}:{text}"
        )
            .Concat(Observable.Return<string>(null))
            .Take(1));
```

Note that now `Test1` and `Test2` retry 5 times each.

There's still a chance that the error gets through, but that's normal coding, right?

Note that I also added `.Concat(Observable.Return<string>(null))` to ensure that the query produces one value if no values comes from the query itself. The `Concat` waits for the main query to end before it concatenates the `null` result, so if the main query produces no values then `null` will come out.

Comment: i actually like how compact this is specifically the take first succesful response, one question i have for that one is would i be able to do a try catch with this and if there isnt at least once succeed the catch would be used? thanks for your responses/comments

Comment: @Ledz3p - I dropped some error handling code for you to look at.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `.Result` if you can help it. There's a cleaner way to grab all the responses.

```
var responses = await Task.WhenAll(requests);
```

One down-side to that approach is that it'll throw an exception if any of the requests throws an exception. So if you want to intelligently handle that case you'll need to try/catch and have some special logic to deal with that.

You can continue that pattern for each asynchronous step, to deal with your results as collections:

```
        var validResponses = responses.Where(r =>r.IsSuccessStatusCode);
        var clientModels = await Task.WhenAll(
            validResponses
                .Select(async r => await r.Content.ReadAsAsync<ClientModel>()));
```

One down-side to this approach is that you end up waiting for all the requests to complete before you start reading any of the response content. So it might make more sense to put the whole process of issuing a request, getting its response, and collecting any data along the way into a single async method, and just say `var responseData = await Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(ThatMethod))`. That way, as soon as one request comes back you can start consuming its response.

When it comes to comparing the results, it's impossible to help without knowing what kind of comparison you're looking for. But let's just say you want the one with the highest value for some property on the model, for instance:

```
        var lastResponseModel = clientModels
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.LastSaved)
            .First();
        return lastResponseModel;
```

Comment: i like the idea of a single async method like you mentioned `var responseData = await Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(ThatMethod))`  do i then still do a foreach in the ResponseData to read the content? thats the only part im unsure of.  And also on your comparison that is helpful i guess i need to figure out exactly what i want to compare and something like the highest value for a property is a good start